# Python dectect the length of the data with socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, unpack

I found this code to detect the length of encrypted data in the frame :

```
header = self.request.recv(5)
if header == '':
   #print 'client disconnected'
   running = False
   break
(content_type, version, length) = struct.unpack('>BHH', header)
data = self.request.recv(length)
```

Souce :

- https://github.com/EiNSTeiN-/poodle/blob/master/samples/poodle-sample-1.py
- https://gist.github.com/takeshixx/10107280
- https://gist.github.com/ixs/10116537

This code, listen the connection between a client and a server. When the client talk to the server, `self.request.recv(5)`  can get you the length of the header in the frame. Then we use that length to take the data.

If we print the exchange between the client and the server :

```
Client  --> [proxy] -----> Server
length : 24 #why 24 ?
Client  --> [proxy] -----> Server
length: 80 #length of the data
Client  <-- [proxy] <----- Server
```

We can see that the client will send two packet to the server.
If i change

```
data = self.request.recv(length)
```

to

```
data = self.request.recv(4096)
```

Only one exchange is made.

```
Client  --> [proxy] -----> Server
length: 109 #length of the data + the header
Client  <-- [proxy] <----- Server
```

My question is why we only need to take a size of 5 to get the lenght, content_type informations ? Is there an understandable doc about this ?

Why there is two request: one with 24 and another with the lenght of our data ?

Answer (score 0):

> why we only need to take a size of 5 to get the lenght, content_type
>   informations ?

Because obviously that's the way the protocol was designed.

Binary streams only guarantee that when some bytes are put into one end of the stream, they arrive in the same order on the other end of the stream. For message transmission through binary streams the obvious problem is: where are the message boundaries? The classical solution to this problem is to add a prefix to messages, a so-called header. This header has a fixed size, *known* to both communication partners. That way, the recipient can safely read header, message, header, message (I guess you grasp the concept, it is an alternating fashion). As you see, the header does not contain message data -- it is just communication "overhead". This overhead should be kept small. The most efficient (space-wise) way to store such information is in binary form, using some kind of *code* that must, again, be known to both sides of the communication. Indeed, 5 bytes of information is quite a lot.

The '>BHH' format string indicates that this 5 byte header is built up like this:

1. unsigned char (1 Byte)
2. unsigned short (2 Bytes)
3. unsigned short (2 Bytes)

Plenty of room for storing information such as length and content type, don't you think? This header can encode 256 different content types, 65536 different versions, and a message length between 0 and 65535 bytes.

> Why there is two request: one with 24 and another with the lenght of
>   our data ?

If your network forensics / traffic analysis does not correspond to what you have inferred from code, one of both types of analyses is wrong/incomplete. In this case, I guess that your traffic analysis is correct, but that you have not understood all relevant code for this kind of communication. Note that I did not look at the source code you linked to.

Comment: Is there a souce where i can find information about the 5 bytes ?

Comment: Sure. Just go on with reading about TLS and you will at some point understand these protocol concepts and corresponding issues (which eventually lead to Heartbleed, Poodle, etc). What I want to say: what you want to do *requires* you to understand what these 5 bytes are in the context of your topic (TLS/SSL, and its vulnerabilities). Do your own research there, it will be inspiring!